# OpenCV imshow/waitkey hangs Python without errors

Tags: python, opencv, ros

I'm using ROS to get a stream of images from a camera and after processing them I show them using this code:

```py
cv2.imshow("image", img)
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

This works for about 30 seconds and then stops working without any errors, apart from the OS(Linux) saying that the window is not responding.

EDIT: I noticed that Python uses 100% of the CPU all the time. Maybe imshow can't keep up?

Comment: we have to see more of your code and your while loop to help you. can you please add the relevant code ?

Comment: There is actually no while loop, there is a function which is a callback for a ROS topic subscription, so it gets called when the camera sends a new image. The function is more than 300 lines of code, if you want I can add only the parts in which we use opencv. Maybe the problem is that it's not called at regular intervals but only when it receives an image?